# Gradle project is not shown in Intellij New Project wizard

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Gradle is installed:

[image]

`Help` says that `Gradle should be available for a new project: 
 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html

[image]

I have the same version of `Intellij` as shown in the `help` : specifically `2019.3.4` .  But `Gradle` does not show up in `New Project` Wizard:

[image]

Why does it not appear?

Comment: did you tried File->invalidate caches and restart inside any project?

Comment: Also checked GRADLE_HOME environment variable is set properly?

Comment: `gradle` _is_ available and able to build some existing projects inside `intellij`

Comment: Check this settings have no errors: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_settings_access

Comment: I double checked, the plugin should be enabled and then invalidate the caches and restart it will come up in the new project menu

Comment: `plugin` was already enabled .. but I `invalidated caches and restart` anyways. Any idea why that would be needed?

Comment: Did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the plugin is enabled in **Installed** tab, not in Marketplace tab.

Comment: It is - but I see your point on asking the question - at the time of the top screenshot it was not. I had subsequently addressed that (yesterday), restarted IJ and the behavior is the same unfortunately.