# Why is Intellij not creating a build.gradle.kts for a new kotlin project?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

`Gradle` is installed:

[image]
I went through the standard `New Project|Kotlin`:

[image]

A JDK was selected and besides that I used the defaults:

[image]

Now we see the new project: but where's the `build.gradle.kts` ?

[image]

Comment: Check that the plugin is enabled in **Installed** tab, not in Marketplace tab.

Comment: @Andrey Yes I did check that. Added screenshot in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a gradle based project (in kotlin) you have to select

```
New Project->Gradle->Check Kotlin DSL BuildScript->Kotlin/JVM
```

If you uncheck the Kotlin DSL BuildScript then `build.gradle` is created while when checking it you'll find a `build.gradle.kts` file

Like this:
[image]

**PS:**

If you want to migrate existing project with Groovy gradle to Kotlin DSL check this out https://medium.com/mindorks/migrating-gradle-build-scripts-to-kotlin-dsl-89788a4e383a

If you want to add gradle to existing non-gradle project right click on project in project structure and then add support for gradle from there

Comment: Problem is - `gradle` is not available for `New Project`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095483/gradle-project-is-not-shown-in-intellij-new-project-wizard

Comment: But in any case that does not mean this answer were incorrect.  I'll award.

Comment: @javadba Thanks! I'll see your another question!